# is there any way to send notification to multiple mobile application users through Aws SNS

Tags: android, ios, amazon-web-services, push-notification, amazon-sns

Is there any way we can send mobile app notifications through Aws SNS to multiple users from custom CRM? Can anyone help me with some end-to-end tutorials for implementing it in CRM in.Net

Comment: That is the exact purpose of Amazon SNS. You can send one message to a Topic and all Subscribers to the Topic will receive the message. Mobile apps are one of the many types of Subscribers (there is also email, HTTP endpoint, Lambda, SQS, etc).

Comment: Thanks john, Can you please help me with some tutorial or something? i am new into it

Comment: [Code examples for Amazon SNS using AWS SDKs - Amazon Simple Notification Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/service_code_examples.html)